# ng build --prod on Azure FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: azure, angular7, ng-build

I'm deploying angular 7 app to Azure, it was working fine, but with the last commit, It gives the error 
`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I have 2 GB RAM , What should I do?
I think it's due to insufficient memroy

here is a full log

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yGQ1.png)

Comment: Are you ng-building the website _on the (machine that runs the) website_? Because you shouldn't. That's what things like [Azure Pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/) are for.

Comment: Actually I'm using Continuos deployment via Bitbucket, I've set Deployment script in Azure and it's run on every commit on related branch @rickvdbosch

Comment: The issue was solved by removing some unneeded packages for now and their styles, but it's not a solution, may I need to do  some optimization